# How can I combine the scores of a multilabel classifier?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, keras, multi-class, multilabel

I have a keras neural network with 8 outputs and it is a multilabel problem, which means that an observation can be classified into more than one target class.

Let's suppose I have the following vector of 8 probabilities (events A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) calculated by the model to a given observation:

**[0.31, 0.45, 0.89, 0.02, 0.43, 0.21, 0.96, 0.32]**

So, we can interpret that:

**P(A) = 0.31, P(B) = 0.45 and so on...**

But what if I want the probability of an observation belong to classes A or B, for example (**P(A or B) = ?**). Or the probability **P(A and B) = ?**

I imagine there are some things to take in consideration, like:

Are the events independent?

1. How can I check the intersection of the events?
2. I would appreciate references of how can I approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**With Normalization**

If we start with the assumption that an object can belong to exactly one class, I think we still can compute the OR probability. Let's normalize the probabilities first, to have their sum as $1$.

```
probs = np.array([0.31, 0.45, 0.89, 0.02, 0.43, 0.21, 0.96, 0.32])
probs = probs / probs.sum()
probs
# array([0.08635097, 0.12534819, 0.24791086, 0.00557103, 0.11977716,
#        0.05849582, 0.26740947, 0.08913649])
```

s.t., $P(C_0 \cup C_1) = P(C_0) + P(C_1)$, and the events that an observation belongs to the output classes are mutually exclusive (so that an observation can belong to exactly one class) and $P(C_0 \; \text{OR} \; C_1)$ can be found with

```
probs[0] + probs[1]
# 0.2116991643454039
```

and $P(C_i \; \text{AND} \; C_j) = P(C_i \cap C_j) = 0, \quad i \neq j$

**Multilabel Classification With Label Powerset**

- This is a classic approach to deal with multi-label classification, which is used to transform a multi-label problem to multi-class problem.
- In this approach, each possible combinations of outputs is treated as a single unique label, i.e., using a mapping from the power set of $C$ to the indices, $2^C \to \{1,2,\ldots,2^{|C|}\}$, where $C=\{C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k\}$ is set of all possible class labels.
- This method allows to compute $P(C_i \cap C_j)$ directly.
- The following example demonstrates the idea, using `skmultilearn`'s implementation of `LabelPowerset`.

  ```
  # generate a sample multilabel dataset 
  from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
  from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset
  from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  import numpy.random as random
  from scipy import sparse

  random.seed(123)
  X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=8, 
                        n_labels=2, # average no. of labels per instance 
                        allow_unlabeled=False,
                        random_state=1)
  y[0:2]
  # array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  #        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

  classifier = LabelPowerset(
                    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(),
                    require_dense = [False, True]
               )
  classifier.fit(X, y)

  classifier.unique_combinations_ 
  # {'1': 0,
  #  '7': 1,
  #  '1,3,7': 2,
  #  '0,6': 3,
  #  '3': 4,
  #  '0': 5,
  #  '6': 6,
  # '0,1,7': 7,
  # '1,4,7': 8,
  # '0,4': 9,
  # '4': 10,
  # '1,3,4,7': 11,
  # '1,6': 12,
  # '0,5': 13,
  # '1,3': 14,
  # '3,4': 15,
  # '1,4': 16,
  # '1,7': 17,
  # '0,1': 18,
  # '0,1,3': 19,
  # '1,3,5': 20,
  # '3,6,7': 21,
  # '5,7': 22,
  # '0,3': 23,
  # '1,6,7': 24,
  # '0,6,7': 25,
  # '3,5': 26,
  # '3,7': 27}

  def get_OR_prob(X, classes=None):
     pred = classifier.classifier.predict_proba(X.reshape(1,-1))[0]
     for combination_id in range(len(pred)):
        if sorted(classes) == 
            sorted(classifier.reverse_combinations_[combination_id]):
        return pred[combination_id]
     return 0
  ```
- Compute $P(C_0 \cap C_6)$ and $P(C_0 \cap C_1 \cap C_6)$:

  ```
  get_OR_prob(X[2], [0,6])
  # 0.19
  get_OR_prob(X[2], [0,1,6])
  # 0
  ```